# Missing transient properties on Domain constructor (with mapped parameters)

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Using the map automatic creation on domain classes doesn't fill in transient properties:

```
class Address {
  String street
  String number
  static transients = ["number"]
}

def address = new Address(street: "King's Street", number: "23")
println address.street //King's Street
println address.number //null
```

Is there any good reason for that? Grails domain instantiation overrides the default Groovy behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by two-way.

1. If you want to make transient a field, you need to bind it.

   ```
   class Address {
   String street
   String number

   static constraints = {
       number bindable: true, nullable:true
   }
   static transients = ['number']
   }
   ```
2. You can bind it using some getter method.

   ```
   class Address {

   String street
   String number

   String getDifferentNumber() { number }

   static transients = ['differentNumber']
   }
   ```

Hope it will help you. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any good reason for that?

Yes.  This has been the behavior since Grails 2.0.2.  Properties which are not bindable by default are those related to transient fields, dynamically typed properties and static properties.  There is some discussion about this at https://spring.io/blog/2012/03/28/secure-data-binding-with-grails.

> Grails domain instantiation overrides the default Groovy behaviour?

Yes.  This allows for doing a number of things which are common in a web app, like binding request parameters to a domain instance in a way that allows for a lot of flexibility needed to bind a bunch of Strings (request parameters) to a graph of objects.

If you really want to bind to a transient property all you have to do is configure the property to be bindable:

```
class Address {
    String street
    String number
    static transients = ["number"]

    static constraints = {
        number bindable: true
    }
}
```

See http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.5/ref/Constraints/bindable.html.

I hope that helps.

Comment: It seems id's are not bindable by default. I'm adding it to the constraints clause as bindable. Would I get in any trouble with that?

Comment: "It seems id's are not bindable by default. I'm adding it to the constraints clause as bindable. Would I get in any trouble with that?" - I can't say if you are going to get yourself into trouble with that or not.  It depends on what your app allows to happen.  Generally folks don't want to bind the id.  If you really do want it bindable and you know what you are doing then go ahead with `bindable: true`, but make sure you understand the implications and you orchestrate things in your app in such a way that you aren't going to be causing problems for yourself.